# Need help identifying this sequence

Tags: sheet-music, classical-music, religious-music

I've been trying to figure out what piece of music this sequence belongs to. I'm not sure the key signature is correct, but I believe the melody and rhythm are correct. If it helps, I'm also pretty sure it's a classical Christmas composition with a choir, but I haven't been able to determine it.

I've tried [searching Musicpedia](https://www.musipedia.org/result.html?sourceid=melody-url&tx_mpsearch_pi1%5bsubmit_button%5d=Search&tx_mpsearch_pi1%5bpc%5d=lilyg%274+d%27%274+d%27%274+c%27%278+d%27%278+e%27%274+c%27%274+d%27%272+&filtertext=&coll=m&onlymatchfrom=0.3) with the sequence as well, with no success. Does anyone know what this is from?

```
X:1
K:C
M:4/4
L:1/4
G d d c/2 d/2 | e c d2 |]
```

Here is what I was trying to render [on an external abcjs editor](https://editor.drawthedots.com/?t=X%3A1%0AK%3AC%0AM%3A4%2F4%0AL%3A1%2F4%0AG%20d%20d%20c%2F2%20d%2F2%20%7C%20e%20c%20d2%20%7C%5D), and a screenshot of the sequence below so the question is somewhat self-contained:

[image: Unknown sequence]

Comment: Having issues with ABCjs notation... sorry the rendering is not correct. I can't figure out what it's missing and it doesn't help that I can't preview the rendered markdown before posting :\

Comment: Yeah, there's a bug with the rendering of abcjs such that it works right only on the first visit to a page, or after a hard refresh. Not great!

Comment: Meanwhile, 1) Welcome! Please check out [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "What is this song" questions aren't covered, sorry. But 2) I agree that it rings a bell. Given the mode and the contour, my guess is an instrumental riff from an arrangement of "Sing We Now of Christmas." Delete the second half of the first measure and you have the opening notes of the melody.